# lucene query special characters

Tags: lucene, special-characters

I have trouble understandnig handling of special characters in lucene.
My analyzer has no stopwords, so that special chars are not removed:

```
CharArraySet stopwords = new CharArraySet(0, true);
return new GermanAnalyzer(stopwords);
```

than I create docs like:

```
doc.add(new TextField("tags", "23", Store.NO));
doc.add(new TextField("tags", "Brüder-Grimm-Weg", Store.NO));
```

Query **tags:brüder\-g** works fine, but fuzzy query **tags:brüder\-g~** does not return anything. When the street name would be *Eselgasse* query **tags:Esel~** would work fine.
I use lucene 5.3.1

Thanks for help!

Comment: Weird is, that when *QueryParser* parses **tags:brüder\-gri** , the *Query.toString()* returns **tags:brud tags:gri**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fuzzy Queries (as well as wildcard or regex queries) are not analyzed by the QueryParser.

If you are using StandardAnalyzer, for instance, "Brüder-Grimm-Weg" will be indexed as three terms, "brüder", "grimm", and "weg".  So, after analysis you have:

- `"tags:brüder\-g"` --> `tags:brüder tags:g`
  This matches on `tags:brüder`
- `"tags:brüder\-g~"` --> `tags:brüder-g~2`
  Since this is not analyzed, it remains a single term, and you have no matches, since there is no single term in your index like "brüder-g"